Garbled characters in Chrome and pycharm. Mac OS Sonama 14.5
From yesterday, my browser shows garbled character when typing in the search bar using Chrome, please see in the attachment. Also, the same issue happens when I open pycharm professional version. It seems like all other applications are not impacted. Does anyone know any solution to this?
Thank you


